# Recreating a text animation (source within)

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, text

I would like to recreate the text animation seen in this screen video I did of this website theme: http://themeforest.net/item/js-responsive-theme/full_screen_preview/7630276

Here is the video to show you the animation:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3HFm_t_vjVpVUNiWVRVdW14aWs/edit?usp=sharing

I am unsure of where to begin and cannot find anything like it through my search so far, I am open to anything to create this such as jQuery. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do this with two absolute positioned texts, one gray (or semi transparent) second one, on top set to `overflow:hidden`. Then I'd just animate the width of the second container.

How do You like the idea? :)

edit:
little tweaking, but idea the same - fiddle for You: http://jsfiddle.net/Lr4PQ/

quite important CSS rule:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

to prevent breaking lines when width of text node is smaller than text's.

edit 2:
Of course, idea behind lets You to achieve the result using pure CSS, jQuery's role is just animating width.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="text upper">You`re the boss</div>
  <div class="text ">You`re the boss</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background:#000;
}
.container {
    position:absolute;
    left:30%;
    top:20%;
    width:auto;
    /*position container as You wish*/
}
.text {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    color:#FFF;
    opacity:.2;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size:30px;
}
.text.upper {
    position:absolute;
    opacity:1;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:0%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.text.upper').animate({width:'100%'},3000).animate({width:'0%'},3000);
```

Comment: Wow, works great and very simply. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: I like this solution cause of "less" (not counting the whole jQuery library) code, xBrowser and maintenance. Just please... jsFiddle is not an alliance of StackOverflow, one day it might drop its services, so always try to include the needed code in your answer.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan  You made great point, i never though of it in terms of reliability. I was led by my own experience that its quite hard to find anything in pasted code, and its really easy to see "how does things work" in live fiddle example. Thank You for making me look at it from different angle!

Answer (score 2):

The animation is achieved in **pure CSS3**:

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/rurakuge/1/edit)**

HTML:

```
<div class="modal">
  <h1 data-content="YOUR BEAUTIFUL NAME">YOUR BEAUTIFUL NAME</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.modal h1 {
    color: #626161;
    font-size: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -125px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
}
.modal h1:before {
    animation: 5s ease 0s normal none 1 loading;
    -o-animation: 5s ease 0s normal none 1 loading;
    -ms-animation: 5s ease 0s normal none 1 loading;
    -moz-animation: 5s ease 0s normal none 1 loading;
    -webkit-animation: 5s ease 0s normal none 1 loading;
    color: #E2E2E2;
    content: attr(data-content);
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
@keyframes loading {
  0% { max-width: 0%; }
}
@-o-keyframes loading {
  0% { max-width: 0%; }
}
@-ms-keyframes loading {
  0% { max-width: 0%; }
}
@-moz-keyframes loading {
  0% { max-width: 0%; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes loading {
  0% { max-width: 0%; }
}
```

One of the reason they used a single `h1` instead of overlaying two `h1` elements and animating the second's one width is simply cause for a better SEO a page should contain only one `h1` element. Also using `content: attr(data-content);` is quite fun so...

Comment: Thanks for your help, but in the jsBin I am not seeing the animation happen :( I don't know if it is my browser perhaps? I am running the latest version of Google Chrome.

Comment: @jjfxx Sorry I forgot (actually I thought it was understandable to omit) to add all the `-browser-specific` properties :) sohuld work now! Happy coding

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Both answers work well but it would only let me accept one and I do not have enough rep to up vote but I appreciate your answer very much, too!

Comment: @jjfxx :) so kind from you! :) thanks! And no problem! I've just shown you how to do exactly the thing you've seen on that page, and that's using CSS3,  but I would also do it with jQuery like Entio did. Happy coding!